# Material-UI : ¿Cómo puedo usar withStyles en un archivo diferente?

Tags: javascript, css, web, reactjs, material

Soy nueva usando react y material-ui, veo que es comun poner los estilos en el mismo archivo pero me gustaría saber como separarlos

aquí hay un [ejemplo](https://codesandbox.io/s/9858w468nw), siempre usan los estilos con cosas como:

```
const styles = theme => ({
  root: {
    ...theme.mixins.gutters(),
    paddingTop: theme.spacing.unit * 2,
    paddingBottom: theme.spacing.unit * 2
  }
});
```

seguido de los componentes que se van a usar:

```
function PaperSheet(props) {
  const { classes } = props;

  return (
    <div>
      <Paper className={classes.root} elevation={1}>
        <Typography variant="h5" component="h3">
          This is a sheet of paper.
        </Typography>
        <Typography component="p">
          Paper can be used to build surface or other elements for your application.
        </Typography>
      </Paper>
    </div>
  );
}
```

y al final se usa:

```
PaperSheet.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

export default withStyles(styles)(PaperSheet);
```

Yo quiero usarlo desde un archivo diferente usando un import como:

```
import styles from 'styles/css/home.module.css';
```

y después usarlo con `className={styles.root}` pero he probado un poco y no me funciona, gracias por sus respuestas (:

Answer (score 0):

Bienvenida a StackOverflow, como veo tu problema lo que sucede es que esos estilos no son CSS son JSS, asi que no los puedes tratar como iguales, una posible solución para lo que necesitas podría ser la siguiente:

1. Separas los estilos en un archivo aparte, digamos ***styles.js*** que tendría la siguiente estructura:

   ```
   const styles = theme => ({
     root: {
       ...theme.mixins.gutters(),
       paddingTop: theme.spacing.unit * 2,
       paddingBottom: theme.spacing.unit * 2
     }
   });

   export default styles;
   ```
2. En tu componente ***PaperSheet.js*** tendrías lo siguiente:

   ```
   /* Otros imports */ 
   import styles from "./styles.js"; // importas los estilos del orto archivo

   function PaperSheet(props) {
     const { classes } = props;

     return (
       <div>
         <Paper className={classes.root} elevation={1}>
           <Typography variant="h5" component="h3">
             This is a sheet of paper.
           </Typography>
           <Typography component="p">
             Paper can be used to build surface or other elements for your application.
           </Typography>
         </Paper>
       </div>
     );
   }

   PaperSheet.propTypes = {
    classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired
   };
   ```
3. Añades el **withStyles** en al final del archivo ***PaperSheet.js*** como lo harías normalmente, y ya podras usar `className={styles.root}`

   ```
   export default withStyles(styles)(PaperSheet);
   ```

Y así ya tendrías tus estilos separados en un archivo diferente, acá te dejo el link de la documentación de Material-ui donde explican un poco como funciona esto de los estilos en javascript https://material-ui.com/customization/css-in-js/, espero que mi repuesta te sirva un saludo y mucha suerte, no dudes en responder o contactarme si tienes mas dudas.